# vb6-how to add progress bar on sql query (mysql)

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have the following code in a form which hangs up the form whenever the query is still executing:

```
Public Function OpenRS(strSql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic

        If IsNull(Cn) = False Then
            rs.Open strSql, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic ', adAsyncExecute
        End If

        Set OpenRS = rs

End Function
```

Tried adding adAsyncExecute but the form closes.

```
Dim RSC As ADODB.Recordset
    Set RSC = Nothing
    Set RSC = Cn.Execute("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & MyDate1 & "','" & MyDate2 & "','DELETE')", , adAsyncExecute)

    While Cn.State = 4
        If frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = 5320 Then
            frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = 0
        Else
            frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + 100
        End If
        'count total records
        'get the current number of records processed
        DoEvents
    Wend
```

How can I add a progress bar to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't tell you how close to finished a query is, it can only tell you how long it's been running or what's impeding progress, as in what other queries are blocking it.

If you have a really long-running query you need to guess how long it will take if you want to compute an ETA.

Comment: Thanks! DoEvents doesn't either.